# Problems with Android and Tomcat. Network unreacheable

Tags: android, tomcat, networking

I'm running an android APP that connects to tomcat server who is in my local network. The app is unable to connect with the server (IP 192.168.0.73:8080) and the logcat says "Network unreacheable".

I have the server and the phone in the same LAN. I connected the phone via wifi and via USB-RJ45 adapter for make connectivity testings.

-I can ping to the server from the phone and from other PC's on the LAN.
-I can telnet the server 8080 port from other PC's on the LAN. But not from the phone using a telnet app.

How can I do?? Any help please??

What can be the problem??

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is with the jdk running on the server. Try to install a new jdk and run your application.

Comment: I have: 

java version "1.6.0_36"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.8) (6b36-1.13.8-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode) 

Can you recommend me a good JDK please??? Thanks!!!

Comment: You could links for new jdk over here < http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/install-jdk.html>